# What is the efficient way of exporting data from hadoop to Oracle handle deletes and with minimum downtime

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have this business requirement where we need to sqoop export data from Hadoop to Oracle since sqoop doesn't efficiently handle deletes we export in overwrite mode. In order to maintain minimum downtime, we developed a process (written as a stored procedure) which executes the following steps in order:

Created STG_TABLES (as staging tables) AND FINAL_TABLES.

Once the sqoop exported data to stg_tables.

1. Stored procedure renames `final_tables` (let's assume we have data in final_tables from previous run) to `temp_tables`
2. The stored procedure renames `stg_tables` to `final_tables`
3. The stored procedure renames `temp_tables` to `stg_tables` and truncates (make them ready for next fresh export).

Do you have any better ideas/suggestions to make improve the above process?

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `FINAL` table as required and add one technical column `load_date` od `DATE` type.

Example:

```
create table FINAL_TABLES  
(load_date DATE,
col1 varchar2(10));
```

Define the `STG`  table with the same structure, but using [`interval partitioning`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-C121EA1B-2725-4464-B2C9-EEDE0C3C95AB.htm)

```
create table STG_TABLES  
(load_date DATE,
col1 varchar2(10))
   PARTITION BY RANGE (load_date)
   INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
( 
  PARTITION p_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('15-03-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
);
```

Now perform the `sqoop` load population the data in the `STG` table. The `load_date` is the *timestamp of the load, equal value in all rows*.

Example simulating with `insert`

```
insert into STG_TABLES (load_date, col1)
values (sysdate,'new load');
commit;
```

In the next step swap the content of the `STG`  and `FINAL` tables using `exchange partition`

```
alter table STG_TABLES
exchange partition FOR (to_date('2020-03-15 05:55:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
with table FINAL_TABLES
without validation;
```

The partition of the `STG` table is identified with the current `load_date` value

Now the loaded data is in the `FILNAL` table and the `STG` table contains the former state if the `FINAL` table.

You can get rid of it by dropping the partition, which van be done immediately of before the next load. The latter option can help with troubleshooting.

```
alter table STG_TABLES
drop partition FOR (to_date('2020-03-15 05:55:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

**Final Notes**

1. The performance of this steps is comparable to your solution with rename table (only data dictionary activities). For the consumer of the `FINAL` table is this option much better, as the table constantly exists, so the queries are not invalidated with the `RENAME`.

   If you defer the `DROP PARTITION` before the next load, even long running queries during the load survive and are continued on the segments of the `STG` table.
2. If the `FINAL` table has indexes, define same index structure on `STG` as `LOCAL` indexes.

   Check that the `STG`  table after the load has all indexes valid

   Add `INCLUDING INDEXES`  to the exchange partition statement.
3. The above described schema defines a *full refresh load*, i.e. the old state is complete overwritten by the new state. You may use the same mechanism for *delta load*, i.e. the new load is *added* the the current state.

   Simple define the `STG` table non-partitioned and the `FINAL` table as partitioned.

The example above will work for a delta load once a day - adjust the INTERVAL schema for different frequencies.